# Highlight text within a string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I have an algorithm which calculates the characters to highlight in text based on query.

For example, if I pass to the algorithm text "1000, Brussels, Belgium" and
query "1000 bruss" it will return me `[[0, 4], [6, 11]]`. But now, I need to write an algorithm which will wrap the characters with `<strong></strong>`, so the result should be `<strong>1000</strong>, <strong>Bruss</strong>els, Belgium`.
I wrote the algorithm, but i have a feeling it might be better or it might be solved more elegant.

```
const highlight = (content, query, matches) => {
  if (!query) {
    return content;
  }

  const openTag = "<strong>";
  const closeTag = "</strong>";

  let result = content;
  let shift = 0;

  matches.forEach(([startIndex, endIndex]) => {
    const s =
      openTag +
      result.slice(startIndex + shift, endIndex + shift) +
      closeTag +
      result.slice(endIndex + shift);

    if (shift) {
      result = result.slice(0, startIndex + shift) + s;
    } else {
      result = s;
    }

    shift += openTag.length + closeTag.length;
  });

  return result;
};
```

Is there any better way to solve the problem?

Another example:

- Text: 'Amsterdam, North-Holland, Netherlands'
- Query: 'amst'
- Matches: `[0, 4]`

Comment: Can matches overlap?

Comment: Why you need `highlight()` to receive the `query` as an argument. If there is no query, it is supposed that the array of `matches` will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the matches in ascending order, then you can just take the parts between the marches and concatenate them alltogether:

```
 const highlight = (content, matches) => {
   matches.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);

  let result = "";
  let prevEnd = 0;
  for(const [start, end] of matches) {
    result += content.slice(prevEnd, start);
    result += "<strong>";
    result += content.slice(start, end);
    result += "</strong>";
    prevEnd = end;
  }
  result += content.slice(prevEnd);
  return result;
}
```

(This assumes that matches do not overlap, just like the OPs code)

---

Alternatively you can leave the replacement up to the regex engine:

```
 const result = content.replace(new RegExp(query.split(" ").join("|"), "g"), it => `<strong>${it}</strong>`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Jonas! I think regex is not gonna work for text: "1000, Brussels, Belgium" and query: "1000 br". Your first example returns `<strong>1000</strong>, Brus<strong>Brussels, B</strong>els, Belgium` but I have a feeling it might be fixed and work fine!

Comment: I have a feeling that `substr` might be replaced with `slice` and it's gonna work fine. What do you think about it?

Comment: @rel1x yup, exactly, I always mix them up ... :/

Comment: @slai the array is already in the wanted order, sorti g can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

#### Consider using [*mark.js*](https://markjs.io/)

Replacing nodes in the DOM can be tricky and lead to unintended consequences as elements shift and fire events.  Although it adds a third party dependency, it has a pretty clean API and abstracts away the logic so you don't have to own it.

```js
var instance = new Mark(".mark-context");
instance.mark("100 bruss");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.min.js"></script>

<p class="mark-context">
  1000, Brussels, Belgium
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative can be to split the string into characters :

```js
var text = '1000, Brussels, Belgium', query = [[0, 4], [6, 11]], chars = [...text];

query.forEach(([from, to]) => { chars[from] = '<strong>' + chars[from]; 
                                chars[to]  = '</strong>' + chars[to] });

document.body.innerHTML = chars.join('')

console.log( chars )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very elegant implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Regular Expressions (RegEx) to do this! See the following function below, simply set `string` to the text you are searching through, and `search` to the text you want to find. In your case, `string` would be "1000, Brussels, Belgium" and `search` would be "1000 bruss"

```
function highlightString(string, search){
var regEx = new RegExp(search, 'g');
return str.replace(regEx, '<strong>'+search+'</strong>');
```

}

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but I don't think it's gonna work when text is "1000, Brussels, Belgium" and query is "1000 br"